# Recurrence formula for win probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

My textbook has this problem

> Two players take turns removing a ball from a jar that initially contains m white and n black balls. The first player to remove a white ball wins. Develop a recursive formula that allows the convenient computation of the probability that the
> starting player wins.

I have done it following way, and I saw another person solving with a different formula. Can someone suggest, with reasons, which one is correct way of doing it?

**My way:**

Probability of first player winning in the first draw $P_1= \frac{m}{m+n}$.

Probability of first player winning in the third draw $P_3= \frac{n}{m+n}.\frac{n-1}{m+n-1}.\frac{m}{m+n-2}$. (first person took black ball out of m white,n blacks, second person took black out of m white, (n-1) blacks, 1st person, then took white ball out of m white, (n-2) blacks).

Rearranging terms, we get $P_3= \frac{m}{m+n}.\frac{n(n-1)}{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)}=P_1\frac{n(n-1)}{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)}$

Similarly, $P_5=P_3\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{(m+n-3)(m+n-4)}$

Continuing this way, we can arrive at the following recurrence formula:

Probability of 1st player winning at the ith draw is $P_i=P_{i-2}\frac{(n+3-i)(n+2-i)}{(m+n+2-i)(m+n+1-i)}$, with base case $P_1=\frac{m}{m+n}$.

**Another way:**

If $p(m, n)$ is the probability that the starting player wins when the jar initially contains m white and n black balls. We have, using the total probability theorem,
$p(m, n) = \frac{m}{m + n}+\frac{n}{m + n}(1 − p(m, n − 1)) = 1 −\frac{n}{m + n}p(m, n − 1)$

The probabilities p(m, 1), p(m, 2), . . . , p(m, n) can be calculated sequentially using this formula, starting with the initial condition $p(m, 0) = 1$.

Comment: Your phrasing suggests that only one of the two ways can be correct. But it isn't apparent whether they actually give different results. For the first, you need to sum up all the ways of winning on odd-numbered turns ($P_1,P_3,\ldots$) to get the probability of victory. For the second, one solves a recurrence relation. Without evidence to the contrary, there's no particular reason to assume that one is right and the other is wrong.

Comment: I wanted opinions/discussions on which way is better. I am thinking, the other person's way may be better, because my way involves more calculations and lengthier. Both ways are giving same results.